# Foundation column gap in Firefox

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have just been asked to edit an existing website that was put together some months ago.

I updated the columns and now there is a gap toward the bottom of the page the size of two project thumbs. It occurs after the fifteenth project thumb. And it offsets the sixteenth project thumb by 8 cols.

I have inspected the site thoroughly but cannot find the css that is creating the gap/offset.

Here is a screenshot of the gap:

[image]

Does anyone have any insight into why this is happening?

http://www.roamfilms.com.au/our-work

Comment: `now there is a gap toward the bottom of the page` this gap? that gap? those gaps? _the_ gap? small gap? big gap? on the left gap? in the middle gap? the gap below the other gap? the 2nd from last gap? There's lots of gaps. Which one in particular are you talking about? In which portion of the 1000+ lines of HTML on that page is this happening? Is there any relevant CSS thats involved? A link to a website and reference to a gap at the bottom of the page isn't enough information to be able to help you.

Comment: Post a screenshot pointing towards the gap.

Comment: Sorry @MLeFevre I will edit the post now. I thought it was really obvious.

Comment: @OfficerrBarbrady It's because not all the items in your grid have the same height, for example if you changed `.columnsPortfolio` to `min-height:155px` then it'll fix what you currently have. The actual problem you have is that most of your images are 460x206, but it looks like you have one image (Buisness GC/Promo) at 469x210, so when they're scaled to a different size, it breaks the grid's height consistency